# content access does not work after changing domain

Tags: 7, rules, users, domain-access

after designing and developing a website I changed its domain. Now any of the permissions are not working. every thing is OK appearently but the functionality is not OK at all.(I mean all the checkboxes and settings are correct but anonymous users have access to all contents!!)

I am using content access module and check the  `Enable per content node access control settings`  option in content type setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rebuild the permissions table.

- Go to /admin/reports/status/rebuild
- Or find the link on the status report: Reports -> Status report and the link is under the Node Access Permissions row.

Comment: wow. thanks. you saved my time and also my life!!!